# How to display WPF FlowDocument in Single Line(Without Wrap)?

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument, flowdocumentscrollviewer

I have created FlowDocument & assign FlowDocument PageHeight = 100.Then i hav added FlowDocument into TextBlock through Inlines.Add method with FlowDocumentscrollViewer.

How to display my FlowDocument content in single line irrespective of FlowDocument PageHeight.
As PageHeight = 100 may displays my Flowdocument content in Multiple line in case content is larger.

Comment: show some example documents.

Comment: you need to provide examples of what you have tried - code, xaml etc